# Add resources to existing azure resource group

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

Today I tried to add new VM into an Azure Resource Group that already has VMs and other resources and it was successful. I removed it and after a while, when a new VM was being added into the same Resource Group, it prompts a new Resource Group would be needed to store the new VM.

I was wondering when a new VM could and could not be added into a Resource Group taken by other resources.

Thanks.

Comment: How you are adding VMs? Using portal, powershell or CLI? Add more details to the question, and also the error/prompt you are getting. By the way, it is allowed to add any number of resource or VMs in a resource group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not the case, you can put almost any resources together in a resource group. there are some weird exception like: windows and linux app service plans cant exist in the same resource group.

you can add resources to different regions in the same resource group as well
you cannot add resources with the same name and type to the resource group, because name + type combination has to be the same

so you can add VM called `new` and VM called `new1`, but not VM called `new` and another VM called `new`; but you can add VM called `new` and Azure SQL called `new` into the same resource group (give that Azure SQL instance called `new` is available, but this has nothing to do with the resource group)

Comment: Hi I tried to add a new VM to a Resource group that already has other resources. it directly prompts " This resource group contains existing resources. Choose an empty resource group or create a new one". How could I avoid this error? Thanks. BTW, I did this on portal.

Comment: this is because you are using the portal and trying to create some resource that portal thinks need to be created in empty resource group. you can work around that by using Powershell\CLI\Rest API\ARM templates. from the portal you cannot work around that

Comment: Hi I got that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This can now be done from the portal.  In your portal at the Home page click Virtual Machines, then Add.  You can then choose the current resource group and add the machine in to it.  May be of use to someone else coming along later like I did.

Comment: Hi Bhixon, I could add a machine in it, but when I select image in the page, I could only choose some of them, not all images, is there any limit on selectable images when adding VMs this way?  Thanks.